# Profile React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How do you display different profile screens depending if it is your own or your friends viewing the profile? Do you need to make two different screens or how does it work. I don't have a code snippet, just curious if anybody knows how to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need one screen, especially when the UI doesn't change depending to the viewer
Just update the state of the component in consequence
If I was asked to do so, I should store the connected user's data in a global state and update the state of the component alike:

```
setStateSomething(username === currentUser.username ? "Something" : "Something else");
```

This is a pseudo code just to show how you can update the state, the key thing is that you only need to update the state of the component not a new component at all as long as the UI stills the same.
Happy coding